# play 2 animationdrawables after each other

Tags: android, animation, animationdrawable

I would like to play 2 animationdrawables after eachother..

When the first one stops, the other one has to start..

The problem is:

AnimationListener is not possible with animationdrawables

Does anybody know a solution?

thank you

Comment: Why not combine them in your XML then

Comment: 1 xml file is oneshot=true
other xml file oneshot=false

that is why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                  public void run() {
                                      //start 2nd animation
                                  }
                                }, delay);//delay is the time for how long 1st animation takes to complete
```